# What constructs end with the keyword "end" in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I remember:

- functions
- do
- if (else, elsif)
- unless
- begin
- while
- for
- until

Is there anything else?

Comment: `class` and `module` come to mind. Is this for a test?

Comment: case, loop, until, proc, lambda.

Comment: `loop` requires keyword `do`. So it's a part of `do`

Comment: Ruby doesn't have functions. Do you mean method definition expressions?

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag Can you please tell me what difference between function and method? The way it returns values?

Comment: @Rajagopalan [Difference between a method and a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/155609/477037)

Comment: @Stefan Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

case, class, module, def(remember, ruby does not have functions, it do have method, and use def keyword to define a method)